# n-sphere and n-torus

Tags: group-theory, geometry, lie-groups

Given the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}$, do we have $\mathbb{S}^n = \mathbb{S}\times\mathbb{S}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{S}$ ($\mathbb{S}$ is the unit circle)? If not, what makes them different?

From Chris Custer's answer, the n-sphere is simply connected while the n-torus is not.

The $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always simply connected while $\mathbb{T}^n = \mathbb{S}\times\mathbb{S}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{S}$ is not simply connected. However, we have $\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{R}/2\pi$, is there any theorem telling the simply-connectedness of a direct-product group?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Note that $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\Bbb Z$.  The fundamental group functor respects products, so $\pi_1(S^1\times\dots\times S^1)\cong\Bbb Z^n$.  But, for $n\ge2$, we have $S^n$ is simply connected.

Comment: For the torus in 6D, look at this nice [animation](https://imgur.com/gallery/mJpIs)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for sharing the wonderful animation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't.  Take $S^2$, the standard  sphere, and $T=S^1\times S^1$, the torus, for starters.  The first is simply connected, whereas the second is not.  Thus they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!